# which is the best way - to store form values in xml

Tags: xml

my current website is HTML based.

my xml:

```
<markers>
<marker nn="00001" name="Starbucks" address="Street1" lat="-22.9063" lng="-43.2098" category="Café" />
<marker nn="00002" name="Tchibo" address="Street2" lat="-22.9013" lng="-43.2048" category="Café" />
...
</markers>
```

Comment: ok, php & asp.net together. O.o

Comment: There is no "best" way. The way you store the values will depend on the way you need to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to deal with XML is to [**avoid it at all cost**](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/xml/). Sane alternatives:

- Simple custom text(UTF-8) formats
- sexprs
- csv
- json
- ndb-like

[The case against xml](http://doc.cat-v.org/xml/the-case-against-xml.pdf)